# Magento 2 Set Product as New when new product is created

Tags: magento2

Whenever I create a new product I want to set the attributes "Set Product as New From" and "To" automatically. For example now(), now()+1month.

Isn't this a core feature and setting in Magento 2?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is such a core feature in magento. But you can easily write a plugin for the class `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` in a module to achieve that. Doing so will run a piece of code before your product is saved to set the new dates. Here's how you do it:

First create a module for it (e.g. Vendor_Module)

Create a di.xml file in the location `etc\di.xml` with the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Plugin_SetNew" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\SetNew"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then you'll need to create a class for the plugin at the location `Vendor\Module\Plugin\SetNew.php`:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class SetNew
{
    public function beforeSave($subject){
        $new_from_date = date("m/d/Y"); 
        $new_to_date = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("+30 day"));

        $subject->setNewsFromDate($new_from_date); 
        $subject->setNewsToDate($new_to_date); 
    }
}
```

Then run `setup:upgrade` for your installation and your new date will be set for one month everytime a product is saved.

Comment: Wow, that property is still named "new**s**_from_date". Backwards compatibility is a bitch.

Comment: haha, yeah. That's not changing anytime soon.

Comment: This is for the Magento 2 add product event, but is there an event for Product Creation during import? So if you are importing new products, they are also set as new using your class? I created a separate plugin using your code and beforeSave does not get triggered when import creates products.

Answer (score 2):

whenever you will add New product from

```
admin->products->catalog->add new product
```

in that you will see after

> Visibility field

there are two date button like

> Set Product as New From //using this you can set new product like 5 days or 15 days

so this is a default functionality using date you can call it on list page a new product or in a custom module also you can get it.

Comment: Hi, Ok but I meant to set "new" automatic when I create a new product.

Comment: ok then for that i think you have to made changes in core modules of magento2